# C# Word Interop, Some shapes not deleted when invoking the .Delete() method

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop, shapes

I am generating shapes in multiple word docs through the Interop library.
Each shape has a textbox presenting some details about it.

Rather than closing the original document after one output has been created then reopening it for the next one I would like to clean the shapes created after having saved the modifications, below the two methods I use to create then clean the shapes :

```
    static void DrawCable(double angle, int identifiant, WdColor couleur)
    {
        float origineX = 365;
        float origineY = 641;
        float extremiteX = (float)Math.Round(origineX + 130 * Math.Cos(angle));
        float extremiteY = (float)Math.Round(origineY - 130 * Math.Sin(angle));

        Shape line = oDoc.Shapes.AddLine(origineX, origineY, extremiteX, extremiteY, ref oMissing);

        Shape etiquette = oDoc.Shapes.AddShape(1, (float)Math.Round(extremiteX - 7 - 7 * Math.Cos(angle) ), (float)Math.Round(extremiteY - 5 + 5 * Math.Sin(angle)), 15, 11, ref oMissing);

        etiquette.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = identifiant.ToString();

    }

    static void CleanDocument()
    {
        foreach (Shape shp in oDoc.Shapes)
            shp.Delete();

    }
```

Whenever I run the code for example with

```
       for (int multiplier = 0; multiplier < 4; multiplier++  )
        {
            Program.DrawCable(Math.PI * multiplier / 2, multiplier, WdColor.wdColorRed);
        }
```

All the Line shapes are deleted just fine but not the "textbox" ones (even if technically here they are AutoShapes - it is the same for Textboxes).
I tested to add an output to see the content of the Shapes collection :

```
static void CleanDocument()
{
    foreach (Shape shp in oDoc.Shapes)
        Console.WriteLine( shp.ID + "\t" + shp.Type.ToString() );

}
```

All the shapes are listed but as soon as I add the shp.Delete() line the Textboxes do not appear to be members of the collection anymore (ie they do not appear anymore in the text output).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The Delete call is altering the collection.  If you do this with a .NET collection then you'd normally get an InvalidOperationException, "the collection has changed" exception.  But not for a Word collection, you probably see only the 1st, 3rd, 5th, etc shape being deleted.  Consider iterating the collection backwards with a normal For loop to avoid this bug.

Comment: Thanks Hans, it worked !